# C# Beginner: If an item from a array was found in a string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, visual-studio, full-text-search

I have a question: for example I have a string and array like this:

```
string text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam";

string[] tags = { "dowaawdlor", "awadwtgmet", "labore"};
```

Now I want an if condition, when one item from the array "tags" was found in the string "text".

```
if( //item from "tags" was found in "text" )
{
//do this
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C#, the preferred approach for any Collection / array related "lookup" / "search" / query / filter / etc operation is [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

```
if (tags.Any(x => text.Contains(x))
{
    //... do this
}
```

**Edit:**

if you need to retrieve the item:

```
var foundtag = tags.FirstOrDefault(x => text.Contains(x));
if (foundtag != null)
{
   //Do something with foundtag.
}
```

Comment: how can i put the entry who was found in an extra variable?